# Changing boolean column type to int

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have a column in my Postgres DB's table that's a boolean type. I want to change it to an integer because I need more than just true/false in that column.

I also want to change all the true values to 1 and the false values to 2.

Is this easily done in Rails? I was trying to do this via a migration file and migrating my DB.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem where you're asking about Y but should have asked about X which led to Y. In other words, you should be asking about the schema and data you're storing and why, instead of modifying the table and trying to map true and false to integers then using the same field for other things.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can do this change with a single migration. The only tricky part is that need to tell the database how to convert the boolean values to your integers.

The way to do this is to use a `USING` clause in the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) to provide the mapping. The raw SQL version would look like this:

```
alter table models
alter column c type integer
using case when c then 1 else 2 end
```

and that translates to a migration thusly:

```
def change
  change_column :models, :c, :integer, :using => 'case when c then 1 else 2 end'
end
```

A boolean column can only contain `TRUE` or `FALSE` so that simple `CASE` should be sufficient. If you're allowing `NULL`s and want to preserve them then:

```
:using => 'case when c is null then null when c then 1 else 2 end'
```

should do the trick.

Of course, you'll have to update all your code to properly work with these new integers by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to modify the database for this? One possible solution is to just create a wrapper method that handles this for you. Let's say you have boolean column named `mycol`, then you could just write a wrapper method that transparently handles this logic without modifying the underlying database.

within your ActiveRecord model:

```
def mycol
  read_attribute(:boolcol) ? 1 : 2
end

def mycol=(value)
  write_attribute(:mycol, value == 1)
end
```

So for instance, running `u.mycol = 1 && u.save` would write `false` to the database and u.reload.mycol would return 1.

However, if it's really necessary to do a migration then create a new integer column to supercede the original boolean column. Don't remove or modify the existing column because want to make sure you're not corrupting or destroying data.

After creating the new column, create a rake task to iterate through all your existing records (use the `find_each` method for the iteration) and set the integer value for the new column based on the value of the original boolean column. Once you've verified the integrity of the data you can drop the original boolean column and replace it with the newly created column.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense :) (I'll follow the second suggestion)

Comment: Actually, is it possible to do it all in migration file. I'm working on my local machine so little risk of f'ing up prod data.

Comment: Possible yes, but be careful doing so. It might cause problems if you run migrations later or if a migration runs twice (non-idempotency). Also, even if your schema is consistent between test/dev/prod the underlying data might not be causing unexpected failed migrations and further headaches.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. It's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Why go through all the trouble of converting the booleans by hand when the database is perfectly capable of doing it for you with a simple USING clause in the ALTER TABLE?

Comment: (1) Separation of concerns. In my opinion, operations altering the schema should be independent from operations mutating data if possible. (2) Idempotency and reversibility of migrations. What happens if that migration runs twice? (3) `using:` isn't document in the Rails migration API. I understand it's dynamically generating the SQL, but that isn't always reliable in my experience

Comment: Also, the ability to access Rails env within a rake task, which can provide flexibility and control. Although this certainly has some drawbacks as well.

Comment: One important advantage of your approach, however, is that it should be atomic and threadsafe, though it will lock table until complete. You can write a transaction for this in ActiveRecord, but is a bit more dangerous.